# Upper/lower bounds don't work as I expect, can not understand why

Tags: c++, lower-bound, upperbound

Here is the code. As a result I get "4 4". Don't understand why it is not "2 4" (according to lower and upper bounds' defenitions).

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {1, 2, 4, 5};
    vector<int>::iterator s , f;
    s = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 3);
    f = upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 3);
    cout << (*s) << " " << (*f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: You misunderstand the definitions. In a case like this when the element is not part of the sequence, they will *always* return the same iterator.

Comment: The two iterators returned by those functions designate a range that holds all the matching values. When there are no matching values the range is empty, so the iterators are equal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`std::lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/):

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range
>   *[first,last)* which does not compare less than *val*.

The first element (from the beginning of the vector) which is not less than `3` is `4` and hence `lower_bound` returns `4`.

From [`std::upper_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/):

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range *[first,last)* which compares greater than *val*.

The first element (from the beginning of the vector) which is greater than `3` is `4` and hence `upper_bound` returns `4`.

The reason for this confusion is because `upper_bound` returns the first element that is greater than the given value, so by symmetry we expect `lower_bound` to return the last element (from the beginning of the vector) that is less than the given value. But alas, the `std` function doesn't obey this "expected" symmetry.

Answer (score 4):

It would be easier to understand/remember what `std::lower_bound()` and `std::upper_bound()` return knowing that [`std::equal_range()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal_range/) returns a pair of iterators, where the first one is equal to what `std::lower_bound()` returns, and the second one is equal to what `std::upper_bound()` returns.

So, here are different cases when they are called with a parameter of `4`:

```
1 2 3 4 4 4 4 5 E
      |       |
      F       S    - first points to the first element, second to the one behind last, representing range which contains 4

1 2 3 4 5 E
      | |
      F S  same for one element

1 2 3 4 E
      | |
      F S  same as before, but 4 is the last element

1 2 3 5 E
      |
      F==S  first == second, which means range for elements equal to 4 is empty

1 2 3 E
      |
      F==S same as before but there is no element greater than 4
```

Where `E` means what `container.end()` returns - an iterator behind the last element.

Comment: Thanks, that actually does help make it easier for me to remember how `(lower|upper)_bound()` work :-)

Answer (score 3):

The naming of `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` is unfortunate as it invites confusion. The names refer to the results when searching through a sequence that has multiple elements that are exactly equivalent to the one you're searching; `lower_bound` returns the iterator to the start, and `upper_bound` returns one past the end.

When the element isn't part of the sequence, they *both* return an iterator to the first element greater than the one you were searching for. This might be the `end` iterator if there are none greater.