# lower_bound() giving unexpected result

Tags: c++, stl, runtime-error, lower-bound

I wrote a code where I need to find `lower_bound` from square number sequence. But lower bound giving me result for `upper_bound`.

**Here is my code & compiler link:**  http://cpp.sh/3cppb

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v{ 1, 4, 9, 16, 25 }; // all the square numbers
   
   int x = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 5) - v.begin() ;
   
   std:: cout<<"Postion "<<x<< "  value  "<<v[x] <<std::endl; //getting output for upperbound
   
}
```

**Output:**

```
Postion 2  value  9
```

**Expected Output**

```
Postion 1  value  4
```

Comment: Why do you expect `std::lower_bound` to return iterator to 4, not 9?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954487/upper-lower-bounds-dont-work-as-i-expect-can-not-understand-why/51954970#51954970

Comment: @Slava Nice explanation there.. I won't forget it. Thanks a  lot. <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) returns the iterator to the first element which is greater or equal to the target value:

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first,
>   last) that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) value, or last
>   if no such element is found.

As `9` is the first value which is greater or equal to `5` (it is greater, of course), the result is totally correct.

If you tried to find an element which is already in `v`, like `9`, then you would get different results for `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound`:

```
std::distance(begin(v), std::lower_bound(begin(v), end(v), 9)); // 2
std::distance(begin(v), std::upper_bound(begin(v), end(v), 9)); // 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications :) . I thought Something is wrong as getting same answers for both lower_bound and upper_bound

Comment: @SyedSohan when element is not in the range, result of `lower_bound` is equal to `upper_bound`, this is what `std::equal_range` returns

Comment: You need to submit `begin(v)` as the first argument to `std::distance` not second.

Comment: @Slava yup, or set -2 and -3 :)

Answer (score 1):

`std::lower_bound` is working correctly.  The function returns the first element that is not less than the value provided.  Since 9 is the first value that is not less than 5 you get that element.

`std::upper_bound` in this case will return the same element as it returns the first element greater than the specified value.  Where you will see a difference is cases like

```
std::vector data = {4,4,4};
auto low = std::lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), 4);
auto high = std::upper_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), 4);
```

In this case `low` will be `begin()` as 4 is not less than 4 while `high` will be `end()` as there is no element greater than 4 in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

The quotation from the Standard, [lower.bound]:

> `template<class ForwardIterator, class T>
>   ForwardIterator lower_bound(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& value);`
>
> Returns: The furthermost iterator `i` in the range `[first,last]` such that for every iterator `j` in the range `[first,i)` the following corresponding conditions hold: `*j < value`.